# How to use VGroup or HGroup in pure actionscript3?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, layout, actionscript, flex-spark

I'm developing a flash app by using free Flex SDK and text editor and compiling in command line.

I want to use VGroup or HGroup in my actionscript to manage positions of DisplayObjects.

I wrote the following code:

```
import spark.components.*
import flash.text.*


var group:VGroup = new VGroup;

var text:TextField = new TextField
text.text = 'abc';

var sprite = new Sprite;
sprite.graphics.lineStyle(2, 0x000000);
sprite.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);

stage.addChild(group);
group.addElement(sprite); // runtime error
group.addElement(text); // compile error
```

But adding Sprite to VGroup causes runtime error:

```
TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed:
cannot convert flash.display::Sprite to mx.core.IVisualElement.
```

And adding TextField to VGroup causes compile error:

```
Error: Implicit coercion of a value of type flash.text:
TextField to an unrelated type mx.core:IVisualElement.
```

How to use VGroup or HGroup in pure AS3?
What is the difference between DisplayObject and IVisualElement?

UPDATE:

I tried the 1st way of www.Flextras.com's answer, SpriteVisualElement and StyleableTextField.
I wrote the following code:

```
package {
    import flash.display.*
    import spark.core.SpriteVisualElement
    //import spark.components.supportClasses.StyleableTextField // compile error
    import spark.components.VGroup
    import flash.text.*

    [SWF(backgroundColor=0xffffff, width=500, height=500, frameRate=12)]

    public class VGroupTest extends Sprite {
        function VGroupTest() {
            //var text:StyleableTextField = new StyleableTextField
            //text.text = 'abc';

            var sprite1:SpriteVisualElement = new SpriteVisualElement;
            sprite1.graphics.lineStyle(2, 0x000000);
            sprite1.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
            sprite1.width = 200
            sprite1.height = 200

            var sprite2:SpriteVisualElement = new SpriteVisualElement;
            sprite2.graphics.lineStyle(2, 0xff0000);
            sprite2.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
            sprite2.width = 300
            sprite2.height = 300

            var group:VGroup = new VGroup;
            group.gap = 10
            group.width = 400
            group.height = 400
            this.stage.addChild(group);

            // the following codes show nothing
            //group.addElement(text);
            group.addElement(sprite1);
            group.addElement(sprite2);

            // the following codes show 2 rectangles
            //this.stage.addChild(sprite1)
            //this.stage.addChild(sprite2)
        }
    }
}
```

But

```
import spark.components.supportClasses.StyleableTextField
```

caused the following error

```
40 Error: Definition spark.components.supportClasses:StyleableTextField could not be found
```

And no SpriteVisualElement is shown on the screen.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the right conceptual approach.  However, elements in a group (or VGroup or HGroup) must implement [IVisualElement](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/IVisualElement.html), which neither [Sprite](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Sprite.html) nor [TextField](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html) implement.

You have a few options to consider:

1. Use a [SpriteVisualElement](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/core/SpriteVisualElement.html) instead of a Sprite; or use a [StyleableTextField](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/StyleableTextField.html) instead of a TextField.
2. Wrap up the Sprite or TextField as a child of UIComponent; then use that UIComponent as the element in the group.
3. Use MX Containers, such as HBox or VBox.
4. Use a UIComponent instead of a Group.  You'll have to write your own layout code in updateDisplayList() for this to work.

My preference is the first approach, followed by the fourth approach.  Approach 2 adds a lot of extra coding, and approach 3 is undesirable due to the dependency on the MX/Halo architecture.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
I tried using SpriteVisualElement(the first Approach).
I created 2 SpriteVisualElements and drawRect on each of them.
And added them to VGroup.
And added VGroup to the stage.
The Errors of both runtime and compile time disappeared.
But unfortunately, nothing was shown on the screen.
Am I missing something?

Comment: Without seeing the code; it is hard to say.  I'm pretty sure a SpriteVisualElement does not size itself.  Did you specify a height and width for your instances?  Is something odd going on, such as the rectangle has the same color as the background?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I added the codes to set width and height but nothing is still shown.
I added a new code to my question. Could you check the code?

Comment: What version of the Flex SDK are you using?  StyleableTextField isn't introduced until Flex 4.5.  Do you have a main application file?  Adding anything directly onto the stage is unusual for a Fle application.  You add items as children on their parent container; never to the stage directly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I'm using Flex SDK 4.5.1.
The code I added to my question is the all code I used to compile.
I wrote that code in a file called `VGroupTest.as`.
And I compiled it with the command, `mxmlc -debug=true
-static-link-runtime-shared-libraries=true VGroupTest.as`.
And `VGroupTest.swf` was created by the command.
`never to the stage directly` means I should use `this.addChild()`(this is
instance of VGroupTest) instead of `this.stage.addChild()`?
Maybe I should give up using VGroup/HGroup and write my own VGroup/HGroup.